# How to check if the property of a class(collection/enumeration of classes) matches to an item from another collection using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a class Product

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
public string Name { get; set; }
    
public string Color { get; set; }
```

Color can be a string like "Blue, Red, Green" or "Red, Brown" etc.

And I have a collection or enumeration of these classes for instance

```
Ienumerable<Product> Products
```

Also I have another string collection of colors like

```
List<string> colorsForFiltering = new List<string>() { Blue, Yellow, Brown}
```

How can I filter Product using Color property throw linq query?
I tried several options including

```
Products = Products.Where(x => colorsForFiltering.Contains(x.Color));
```

and many others. I know that this query is wrong. I'm sure i can solve this problem using cycles. But i wanted to know if it is possible to do that using linq. Unfortunately I cant find the answer. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `x => colorsForFiltering.Any(x.Color.Contains)`

Comment: are you sure that the last line isn't working? whats the result? seems right for me

Comment: @ThomasKlammer `x.Color` could contain a comma-delimited string of colours e.g. `"Red, Brown"`.

Comment: ah ok - i have overseen that

Comment: Don't store lists as stringified comma separate values.  Store an actual list of colors if a product has a list of colors.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay thank you, it helped. I just used All instead of Any, this is more suitable for my current needs

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Johnathan Barclay in comments solved the issue

```
x => colorsForFiltering.Any(x.Color.Contains)
```

i just used All instead of Any

Comment: This breaks anytime a color's name is contained in another's, which is quite common.  A product that's light blue and a filter for blue will consider it a match, even though it's not.

Comment: @Servy i can agree, but colors was just an example, real property contains other information, but thank you, for the remark

Comment: The most important thing is that i didn't know that i can use these linq methods in such a manner

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should change `Color` to an `IEnumerable<string>`, but with what you have you can do:

```
Products = Products.Where(x => colorsForFiltering.Intersect(x.Color.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries).Any());
```

Note that this will almost certainly not be translatable to SQL so you'll have to do it in memory. An alternative that is SQL-translatable would be to loop through the filter colors:

```
var results = colorsForFiltering.SelectMany(c=>
        Products.Where(x => x.Color.Contains(c))
    );
```

This is not foolproof either, since if you have any colors that are substrings of another color (e.g. "Blue-Green", then `Contains` will match the substring, but it is translatable to SQL